# Heroku Postgres app works on local machine but not on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, postman

I built and deployed a Node.js Postgres app to Heroku and can not get to any of my endpoints via the Heroku site except the root GET route. Curiously, when I run `Heroku local web` ALL my endpoints behave exactly as they should. I can successfully perform CRUD on the app running via `Heroku local web`. However, when I try, for instance, to create a user using the Heroku URL, it returns an empty error message. Yet, when I check the associated database I find that the user was indeed created. Other than returning an empty error message when I try to either create a user or sign it, the app correctly responds with the different errors I programmed. For example, when I tweak my login details or try to register the same user I earlier tried to register it correctly says the user already exists!. Still, when I try to log in that same existing user I get a blank error message. Note that I created both the Heroku PostgreSQL database and my local PostgreSQL database from exactly the same queries. Please, can you help me through this bottleneck? I am using Postman to test my APIs.
[Test to sign in user on Heroku app running on the local machine: success!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46OVb.png)

[Same exact test with Heroku URL: cryptic error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx6YV.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I don't think it's possible to diagnose this without seeing the code (and possibly environment setup, i.e. your `package.json` if any). Ideally you'd try to trim your application down to the minimum that still produces this error and share that code so people here can take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lot of researching and fiddling around I discovered the solution. I did not add keys from my `.env` file to Heroku as `config vars` found under the settings tab of the Heroku User dashboard. Manually adding my environment variables resolved the matter. Now my app is working both on my local machine and via the Heroku URL.